# A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. Error 10054

Tags: sql-server, errors, azure

I have been using SQL Server & Azure for almost two years with Zero problems. Now for some reason I am getting the following error when I try to connect to my Azure database from SSMS. I have tried everything I could find: extend connection time-outs, checked open firewall port 1433, used my phone Hotspot to make internet connection, turned off public and private firewalls (temporarily for testing)... with no difference.  I have Azure BASIC service and the database only holds dummy information for testing.

Everything in the Azure Portal looks fine. I can't find any errors or outages. The only thing I thought was weird was that my Server is in "West Europe" (I'm in Florida). And my Storage Account is in "East US". Maybe that's not unusual though?

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------
Error connecting to 'gobo.database.windows.net'.
------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
------------------------------
An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
------------------------------
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10054)
------------------------------
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Tried testing with Azure Data Studio, where I could connect and I could run a query against a datatable successfully, however when I tried to expand the server list to show the database I got the following:

[image]

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified network name is no longer available
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.GetExecuteReader(SqlCommand command)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.GetExecuteReader(SqlCommand command)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecuteSql.GetDataReader(String query, SqlCommand& command)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataProvider.SetConnectionAndQuery(ExecuteSql execSql, String query)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecuteSql.GetDataProvider(StringCollection query, Object con, StatementBuilder sb, RetriveMode rm)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObjectBase.FillData(ResultType resultType, StringCollection sql, Object connectionInfo, StatementBuilder sb)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObjectBase.FillDataWithUseFailure(SqlEnumResult sqlresult, ResultType resultType)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObjectBase.BuildResult(EnumResult result)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabaseLevel.GetData(EnumResult res)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData(Request req, Object ci)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.GetData(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.GetEnumeratorDataReader(Request req)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.GetInitDataReader(String[] fields, OrderBy[] orderby)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.ImplInitialize(String[] fields, OrderBy[] orderby)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.Initialize(Boolean allProperties)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.OnPropertyMissing(String propname, Boolean useDefaultValue)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.PropertyCollection.RetrieveProperty(Int32 index, Boolean useDefaultOnMissingValue)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database.get_IsSqlDw()
at Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer.ObjectExplorer.SmoModel.DatabaseTreeNode.EnsureContextInitialized() in D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer\ObjectExplorer\SmoModel\DatabaseTreeNode.cs:line 32
at Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer.ObjectExplorer.SmoModel.SmoTreeNode.GetContext() in D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer\ObjectExplorer\SmoModel\SmoTreeNode.cs:line 98
at Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer.ObjectExplorer.Nodes.TreeNode.GetContextAs[T]() in D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer\ObjectExplorer\Nodes\TreeNode.cs:line 310
at Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer.ObjectExplorer.SmoModel.DatabaseTreeNode.PopulateChildren(Boolean refresh, String name, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer\ObjectExplorer\SmoModel\DatabaseTreeNode.cs:line 46
at Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer.ObjectExplorer.Nodes.TreeNode.Expand(String name, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer\ObjectExplorer\Nodes\TreeNode.cs:line 248
at Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer.ObjectExplorer.ObjectExplorerService.<>c__DisplayClass36_0.<QueueExpandNodeRequest>b__0(IBindingContext bindingContext, CancellationToken cancelToken) in D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer\ObjectExplorer\ObjectExplorerService.cs:line 440
at Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer.LanguageServices.BindingQueue`1.<>c__DisplayClass34_2.<ProcessQueue>b__1() in D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer\LanguageServices\BindingQueue.cs:line 352
```

I am at a total loss. Have spent 10+ hours on this with no progress. Any help would be appreciated. I am self taught and understand enough to use, but not experienced enough to do in depth debugging...

I installed sqlcmd and was able to connect to the server and query against the database, but I'm not sure what that tells me about the problem.

Comment: It looks like the network connection is getting dropped. Try running a network trace, such as with [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), to monitor the TCP traffic.

Comment: The error message indicates that the connection was *forcibly* closed by the host--this often indicates a firewall blocking the request, but in your case, sqlcmd works, disproving that. The stack trace from ADS indicates the problem is in loading Object Explorer--which is probably what is happening in SSMS, too.  What version of SSMS & other SQL Tools do you have installed on your machine? My hunch is a shared component/dll may be to blame.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! I'm not familiar with Wireshark, but I will look into it today. I am using SSMS v17.9.1 and downloaded/installed sqlcmd yesterday. Also (if that helps troubleshoot), I am working on a VS Community 15.8.1 C# project and I have similar problem connecting to my Azure database for there.

Comment: I ran Wireshark. I don't fully understand the network traffic, but there was nothing glaring that screamed error or such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone runs into a similar problem... After 1.5 hours on the phone with MSFT, and reinstalling both SSMS and VS with no resolution. I reformatted my machine, reinstalled, and now everything works the way it should. I don't know what got into my system but now it's gone. Not a great solution, but that's what worked.

UPDATE: When the problem reoccurred again, and after four more "reformats", the root of the problem was the Network Driver for my machine. Although Windows Update reported that I had the latest driver, there was a newer driver on the manufactures website that seems to have solved the problem.

Product Type: Killer(R) Wireless-AC 1550 Wireless Network Adapter (9260NGW) 160MHz 
Product Type: Killer E2500 Gigabit Ethernet Controller

Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 17763) (17763.rs5_release.180914-1434) 
System Manufacturer: Alienware BIOS: 1.6.5 (type: UEFI)

Comment: The drive update worked for me. You are my love man :*

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue with the creation of an index that was taking too long. Didn't work on SSMS, got it working on Azure Data Studio.